# Rails 4: How to update a collection_select based on another collection_select through AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

**The problem:**
I need to filter a collection of **Units** based upon the selection of a collection of **Organizations.**

Upon selecting an **Organization**, the **Unit** dropdown-menu should refresh to show only the **Units** that belong to informed **Organization**.

I've checked these questions:

- [Rails forms: updating collection_select options based on other collection_select value using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904654/rails-forms-updating-collection-select-options-based-on-other-collection-select)
- [UJS, AJAX, Rails 4, form_for collection_select to pass value into method and return value back to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073795/ujs-ajax-rails-4-form-for-collection-select-to-pass-value-into-method-and-ret)
- [ajax in rails with collection_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404285/ajax-in-rails-with-collection-select)
- [How to add an onchange event to select tag in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979400/how-to-add-an-onchange-event-to-select-tag-in-rails)
- [Rails forms: updating collection_select options based on other collection_select value using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904654/rails-forms-updating-collection-select-options-based-on-other-collection-select)
- [Rails form_for collection_select ignoring remote ajax call that select_tag accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680893/rails-form-for-collection-select-ignoring-remote-ajax-call-that-select-tag-accep)
- [remote select, controller needs more form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970454/remote-select-controller-needs-more-form-data)

And these documentations:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

This is my code so far:

**Models**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units
  has_many :projects, through: :units
end
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :projects
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizaton
  has_one :organization, through: :unit
end
```

**Views**
  *app/views/projects/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :organization_id, Organization.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :unit_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :unit_id, Unit.all.where(organization_id: :organization_id), :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controllers**
  *Projects Controller*

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :organization_id, :unit_id)
end
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I made it, the solution was pretty simple, but the lack of updated material regarding this simple issue made it a chore bigger than it should have:

*config/routes.rb*

```
 get 'filter_units_by_organization' => 'projects#filter_units_by_organization'
```

*controllers/projects_controller.rb*

```
def filter_units_by_organization
  @filtered_units = Unit.where(organization_id: params[:selected_organization])
end
```

*views/projects/filter_units_by_organization.js.erb*

```
$('select#project_unit_id').html('<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@filtered_units, :id, :name) %>');
```

*assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
$(function() {
    $("select#project_organization_id").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:  "/filter_units_by_organization",
            type: "GET",
            data: { selected_organization: $("select#project_organization_id").val() }
        });
    });
});
```

*views/projects/_form.html.erb*

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :organization_id, Organization.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Please select' } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :unit_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :unit_id, Unit.all.where(organization_id: :organization_id), :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: How I can do this same for turbo?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing an duplicate `organization_id` on the `projects` table you should set the relationship up to go through the Unit model.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units
  has_many :projects, through: :units
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit
  has_one :organizaton, through: :unit
end
```

This avoids the awkward issue where you have to ensure that a unit and a project have the same `organizaton_id`.

This also means that you no longer need a input to select the organization when creating a Project - just the unit.

Comment: If you still want to have the organization select for the user to be able to narrow down the options you would need to implement it as an ajax call. However that is whole tutorial in itself and might be better left for later if you are new to rails.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @max, I'll refactor the code with your answer :) about ajax, I guess that's what I actually intended, I'll reword the question. I've done a few basic things with ajax on rails, like a livesearch filter, sorting and pagination, also setting the view templates to respond into modals, but my knowledge in this "conversation" between JS and Rails is very limited, do you know any places where I could learn more about it? Thanks

Comment: I don't use `js.erb` or the built in `remote: true` options. IMHO it just leads to a total clusterfuck of server side and client side logic and awful API's. Its one of the worst parts of rails. I use just plain old jquery ajax handlers together with JSON responses from the controller.