# Populate dropdown list upon selecting a value from another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate one drop down list based on the selection of another drop down list in my rails project. The only difference is that both drop down lists should be populated from one model.

The model is **City**, and it has **name** and **state**.

**name** is the city name, and **state** is the state to which the city belongs.
For example, a city object would be :

```
id = 1
name = LOSANGELES
state = CA
```

I've checked [Rails 4: How to update a collection_select based on another collection_select through AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230426/rails-4-how-to-update-a-collection-select-based-on-another-collection-select-th)
 and other links but I can't seem to figure out how to populate the city drop down list from the same Model as the first dropdown

Here's my code :

controllers/city_stats_controller.rb :

```
def city_stats
@state = params[:state]
@cities = City.select(:name).all.where(:state => state)

 respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => @cities }      
 end
end
```

views/city_stats/city_stats.html.erb :

```
<div class="row">
    <label>State <span>*</span></label>
    <%= collection_select :city, :state, City.select(:state).uniq.order('state ASC'), :id, :state, {:prompt => 'Select a State'}, {id: 'state', multiple: false} %>

    <label>City <span>*</span></label>
    <%= collection_select :city, :name, [], :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select a City'}, {id: 'name', multiple: false} %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#state").on('change', function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/admin/city_stats",
    type: "GET",
    data: {state: $(this).val()},
    success: function(data) {
      $("#city").children().remove();
      // Create options and append to the list
      var listitems = []; 
      $.each(data,function(key, value) { 
        listitems += '<option value="' + key+ '">' + value + '</option>';    }); 
    $("#city").append(listitems);
    console.log(listitems);
     }
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem? Any error you are getting ?  Which part of code not working?

Comment: @krishnar I don't get any error, it's just that the city drop down list is not populated after I select a certain state from the first dropdown list

Comment: wether you are getting request whenever state dropdown value changed?

Comment: check my solution.I think that should work for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***change your city_stats method like. This method should return id and name***

```
def city_stats
  @state = params[:state]
  @cities = City.where(:state => state).select(:id, :name)

  respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => @cities }      
  end
end
```

**Change your each function in  ajax call like this.Since data in response is array of object we are using value.id, value.name .**

```
$.each(data,function(key, value) { 
  listitems += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';    
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your answer.. I think you confused the name of the action in the controller which is (city_stats) and not city_state. The id of the first select is state, whereas the id of the second one is city

Comment: Should the id be the name of the column itself? Like for the first collection_select the id would be state, and for the second one it would be name?

Comment: What's confusing me is the fact that both name and state are within the same class City, so I'm not really sure what to put there..

Comment: I replaced the ids as you mentioned in your answer but stil not getting the second dropdown list populated upon the first selection :/

Comment: @GeoSal whenever you change state whether it hitting server?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so? How can I be sure? In my collection_select for the state I do City.select(:state).uniq.order('state ASC').. When I click on the dropdown I can clearly see the list of states

Comment: I mean whenever you change state, can you see request in rails c? and what is the response your getting?

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry my bad.. Actually I don't.. This is the response I'm getting on Rails : Processing by CityStatsController#city_stats as HTML
 City Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cities"."id" FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."state" IS NULL AND "cities"."name" IS NULL
***********#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
 City Load (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "cities"."state" FROM "cities"  ORDER BY state ASC

Comment: Can u show what coming in data.  i mean ajax success data

Comment: @GeoSal  I understood mistake. I updated code. It should work for u. Try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @krishnar! I changed the code following your update, but I'm still not getting the city dropdown list populated. The rails response however now is : Parameters: {"state"=>"CA"}
  City Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cities"."id" FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."state" = $1 AND "cities"."name" IS NULL  [["state", "CA"]]
***********#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155447/discussion-between-krishnar-and-geosal).