# How to populate a collection based on another collection's selected field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm developing RoR service and I'm stuck with this problem. 
I have the following models and a view that is a basic `simple_form` form. The desired behavior should be: select a client from a collection and then, based on the selected client, select one of the client's projects from the other collection. 
My problem is that I can't find a way to do this. To be more clear, I can't find a way to pass the id of the selected client to the next collection.

client.rb

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :projects
end
```

project.rb

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
end
```

_form.html.erb

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @day do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :client_id, collection: Client.all %>
    <%= f.input :project_id, collection: Project.where(<it should take client_id value) %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this is clear enough and, of course, feel free to ask for any ulterior info.
Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: With MrYoshiji's help I quite figure out the problem and my searches became more precise. So I found this question (I swear I didn't see it before).
[Rails 4: How to update a collection_select based on another collection_select through AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230426/rails-4-how-to-update-a-collection-select-based-on-another-collection-select-th)

Comment: Do some experiment with your code; we can't provide full code implementation here.. for reference you can use it `https://rubyplus.com/articles/3691-Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-5`

Comment: Of course, that wasn't the idea at all. I wrote the post to have some help/reference from someone more experienced than me, not a full implementation.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: You will need to make an asynchronous javascript request (AJAX call) to your server on each change of the `client_id` select tag's value to interrogate which Projects are available for that `client_id`. The other option is to load all `projects` at once in the form but this is obviously a non-scalable approach.

Comment: Yep that was my idea. But I'm not sure on how to refresh the collection after the result of the get is retrieved.